# How to get the minimum addition result from 2 arrays within k swaps?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

I ran into an interesting algorithm(maybe :/) question, and as I am just starting out with algorithms and data structure, it's a little bit hard for me to resolve. Could you please have a look and maybe give me some advice :)

Here is the question:
There are two integer arrays with same length - n, one switch number k which allows **at most** k times swap between 2 arrays, how to find the minimum addition result after k swaps?

Something important is:

> Between 2 swaps, the elements should come form same array!
>
> It may be a little confusing........ here is the example:

```
ex:           
     {1, 5, 3, 2, 4}  Array A          
     {3, 4, 1, 6, 2}  Array B       
     k - 2            Max swap chance 
     the minimum result should be 1-A[0] + 4-B[1] + 1-B[2] + 2-A[3] + 4-A[4] = 12
                                      first swap         second swap
                                       A -> B               B -> A
There is path like :
                      1        2   4
                         4  1
```

**Please note** that:

> If we choose A[0] (because A[0] < B[0] ), then Array A have to be the **base** array.

```
And the swap here:  1 A[1] ->  4 B[1]  is the first swap 
                    after above swap, the next number have to be 1 (B[2]) if we do not do another swap from B to A
                    1 A[3] ->  2 B[3] is the second swap
```

In my example:

We choose 1 in Array A, then the  first swap(*replace*) happens between A[1] and B[1],
and after second swap happens at A[3], we could not do more swap now because k has reached to 2 (k should <= 2)

In the following case:

```
          {1 5 3 7 1 1 3}
          {3 1 4 1 3 9 2}
             ^       ^
 if we only have at most 2 chance to swap, they should happen at '^' because 
           1         1 3
             1 4 1 3       
 could result in minimum addition result
```

Lets make it more general:

```
     {1, 5, ... , 3, ... , 2, 4}  Array A          
     {3, 4, ... , 1, ... , 6, 2}  Array B       
     k - n            Max swap chance 
     The key point here is: how could I decide whether the first swap should still
happen between A[1] and B[1] or there may be another better chance to do a swap
between A[i-th] and B[i-th] .
     And we only have at most k times swap chance, so when and where should the
k swaps happen need to be considered carefully..
```

I am trying to make the question more clear, if there is still something confusing, please tell me.
Any ideas of how to decide where to swap and how many times to swap and finally get the minimum calculation result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn't a C# or Java question. You can use the `[language-agnostic]` tag for language-independent questions. :-)

Comment: is this *swap array items* or *switch between arrays*?

Comment: @greybeard emmm... it should be 'switch', and i thought 'swap' could make the question looks easier.... but maybe i am wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I've understood you right you have `2` possibilities:

1. swap items of each pair of `i`-th items to make `A` array contain min items
2. swap items of each pair of `i`-th items to make `B` array contain min items

In your case:

Let's make `A` have min items:

```
 {1, 5, 3, 2, 2}  Array A          
 {3, 4, 1, 6, 4}  Array B     
 ---------------
 {1  4  1  2  2}  Min (based on A, 2 swaps)
     ^  ^
     swap (we take items from B)
```

Let's make `B` have min items:

```
 {1, 5, 3, 2, 2}  Array A          
 {3, 4, 1, 6, 4}  Array B     
 ---------------
 {1  4  1  2  2}  Min (based on B, 3 swaps)
  ^        ^  ^
     swap (we take items from A)
```

Here `2 < 3` so we should make `A` contain minimum items and we can do it in `2` swaps

So far, so good in general case you can

1. Count swaps (let it be `swapsA`) required to make `A` contain min items of each pair.
2. Count swaps (let it be `swapsB`) required to make `B` contain min items of each pair.
3. Return `Min(swapsA, swapsB)`

Possible **C#** code

```
int[] A = ...
int[] B = ...

int swapsA = 0;
int swapsB = 0;

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; ++i) {  
  sum += Math.Min(A[i], B[i]); 

  if (A[i] > B[i]) 
    swapsA += 1; 
  else if (A[i] < B[i]) 
    swapsB += 1;
}

int swaps = Math.Min(swapsA, swapsB);

Console.Write($"We have to make at least {swaps} swaps; the min sum is {sum}");
```

**Edit:** the only *diffiuclty* is when items are *equal*, e.g.

```
 {1, 5, 1, 2, 4}  Array A  # note that 3d and 4th pairs have equal items        
 {3, 4, 1, 2, 2}  Array B     
 ---------------
 {1  4  1  2  2}  Min (based on A, 1 swap)
     ^        ^
     swap (we take items from B)
```

Let's make `B` have min items:

```
 {1, 5, 1, 2, 4}  Array A          
 {3, 4, 1, 2, 2}  Array B     
 ---------------
 {1  4  1  2  4}  Min (based on B, 2 swaps)
  ^           
     swap (we take items from A)
```

note, that in general case `swapsA + swapsB <= A.Length`

**Edit 2:** If you have up to `K` swaps to perform you can order them and take `K` the *most promising* (with maximum `A[i] - B[i]` difference):

Let's swap and sum `A`

```
      {1 5 3 7 1 1 3} A 
      {3 1 4 1 3 9 2} B
         ^   ^     ^
         reasonable swaps - 3 - more than allowed 2

      {5, 1} drops sum by 5 - 1 == 4 # most promising (a best sum drop)
      {7, 1} drops sum by 7 - 1 == 6 # most promising (a best sum drop)
      {3, 2} drops sum by 3 - 2 == 1
```

the most promising swaps are `{7, 1}` and `{5, 1}`. So we have `1 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3`.

Let's swap and sum `A`

```
      {1 5 3 7 1 1 3} A 
      {3 1 4 1 3 9 2} B
       ^   ^   ^ ^ 
       reasonable swaps - 4 - more than allowed 2

      {1, 3} drops sum by 3 - 1 == 2 # most promising (a best sum drop)
      {3, 4} drops sum by 4 - 3 == 1
      {1, 3} drops sum by 3 - 1 == 2  
      {1, 9} drops sum by 9 - 1 == 8 # most promising (a best sum drop)
```

So we have `{1, 3}` and `{1, 9}` swaps more promising and the sum is `1 + 1 + 4 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 2`.

Finally you should compare both possibnbilities (if you make minimum sum from `A` or from `B`)

Comment: thanks for reply :-) but im still confused with how could I know how many times it should do swap,  like , if the 4th element of Array B is 2, then it should not do second swap...

Comment: @ColinXu: that's why I put `(A[i] > B[i])` and `(A[i] < B[i])`, not `<=` and `>=` in may sample code. we swap if and only if item is *strictly* larger (smaller)